# Как правильно использовать Git для Unity?

Tags: unity3d, git, github, unity3d-editor, git-lfs

Есть небольшой проект, в котором мы используем репозиторий на GitHub для совместной работы в Unity. Всё было хорошо, пока к нашим данным не подключился художник и размер его текстур был больше 100 Mb, поэтому Git предложил использовать LFS. Как обмениваться текстурами и моделями во время работы, чтобы это не заполняло хранилище Git?

Comment: Вместо git используйте решения digital asset management.